# Why i can excute a newly created file which is not executable?

Tags: linux

In Ubuntu, The default umask on Ubuntu is `022` which means that newly created files are readable by everyone, but only writable by the owner, nobody can excute it.
In this case, i create a new file :

```
touch test.rb  # Its content is: puts "hello world"
ls -l demo.rb  # -rw-r--r--
```

Then i excute `test.rb` :

```
ruby test.rb  # output: "hello world"
```

Since the owner of the file does not have the "x" permission , then why I can successfully run the file ? or I have missed some knowledge about it ?

Comment: If a file it executable, it can be executed by the system. For example if there is a file called find.sh, you can execute the file natively on the shell as `./file.sh` or `file.sh`(if it is in path). What you have done is executed the command `ruby` on the shell and it has handled test.rb. You didn't execute `test.rb` on the shell

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not executing the file as a binary. You are executing `ruby` binary with argument `test.rb` and it interprets the Ruby script. Therefore, only `ruby` binary needs execution privilage and not the script itself.

You can check the privileges of the binary by running `stat (which ruby)`.

On the other hand if you place

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby
```

on the top of your script and make it executable with `chmod a+x test.rb` you could then make Linux run it. The `binfmt` module of the kernel will check search for `#!` (called shebang) in the file and run the interpreter for you.

You can find this shebang in lot of the shell scripts. Nowadays it is common to put `#!/usr/bin/env ruby` or `#!/usr/bin/env python` in order to  use interpreter binary in other location that is available on `PATH` variable like `/usr/local/bin/ruby`. Again `env` is just another binary program. It will run its argument as a program. The kernel will pass script as the parameter which will result in command `/usr/bin/env ruby test.rb`.

Answer (score 1):

Grzegorz Żur is right.

you can modify your test.rb like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
puts 'hello world'
```

and then you excute it with `.`:

```
$ ./test.rb
```

you will see `Permission denied`.

Comment: Thank you for your simple code. it's clear for me now